# value stored as text after update data userform

Tags: excel, vba

after update sheet with data, the value has been entered through the user form stored as text, however, the number is entered through textbox, which makes an error on the formula that depends on that number
cell format change after sending data, however, change the format to number every time update data

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Module")
ws.Cells(2, 39).Value = TextBox4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I get exactly your Problem, but when you want to use your textbox-values for functions you need to convert the textbox-Content as a number-format otherwise you'll get an error in Excel-Functions.

Try `Worksheets("Module")ws.Cells(2,39).Value=CLng(Textbox4)` --> CLng for Long.

Answer (score 0):

An example how to control the input if it is a number

```
Dim a ad Variant

a = InputBox("Enter the number")

If Not IsNumeric(a) Then 'a is not a number 

Else 'a is a number and can be converted to Integer 
ws.Cells(2,39).Value= CInt(a) 
End If
```